# Why does comparison of floating-point to infinity work?

Tags: c, floating-point, infinity

As anyone knowledgeable enough will know, you cannot compare two floating-point numbers with simple logic operators and expect a logical result.

Why then, does a logical EQUAL TO comparison to `INFINITY` always return true when the number is, in fact, `INFINITY`?

**PS:** I tried the same comparison with `NAN`, but it seems only `INFINITY` can be reliably detected as being equal to another number of the same value.

(Edit) Here is my implementation's (GCC) definition of `INFINITY` and `NAN`:

```
#  define INFINITY (__builtin_inff ())
#  define NAN (__builtin_nanf (""))
```

Comment: `inf == inf`, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @phuclv If n is a floating-point number, then `nan != nan` and `n != n` (for the most part). Why can I always detect `inf` and ONLY `inf`?

Comment: If you really need to find out if a value is NaN or infinity, then use the standard [`isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) and [`isinf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isinf) functions. Pay close attention to [the notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan#Notes) of `isnan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As anyone knowledgeable enough will know, you cannot compare two floating-point numbers with simple logic operators and expect a logical result.

This has no basis in the IEEE 754 standard or any other specification of floating-point behavior I am aware of. It is an unfortunately common misstatement of floating-point arithmetic.

The fact is that comparison for equality is a perfect operation in floating-point: It produces true if and only if the two operands represent the same number. There is never any error in a comparison for equality.

Another misstatement is that floating-point numbers approximate real numbers. Per IEEE 754, each floating-point value other than NaN represents one number, and it represents that number exactly.

The fact is that floating-point **numbers** are exact while floating-point **operations** approximate real arithmetic; correctly-rounded operations produce the nearest representable value (nearest in any direction or in a selected direction, with various rules for ties).

This distinction is critical for understanding, analyzing, designing, and writing proofs about floating-point arithmetic.

> Why then, does a logical EQUAL TO comparison to INFINITY always return true when the number is, in fact, INFINITY?

As stated above, comparison for equality produces true if and only if its operands represent the same number. If `x` is infinity, then `x == INFINITY` returns true. If `x` is three, then `x == 3` returns true.

People sometimes run into trouble when they do not understand what value is in a number. For example, in `float x = 3.3;`, people sometimes do not realize that C converts the `double` `3.3` to `float`, and therefore `x` does not contain the same value as `3.3`. This is because the conversion operation approximates its results, not because the `value` of `x` is anything other than its specific assigned value.

> I tried the same comparison with `NAN`,…

A NaN is Not a Number, so, in a comparison for equality, it never satisfies “the two operands represent the same number”, so the comparison produces false.

Comment: I understand. So, given two numbers can be reliably approximated to a single, same value every time (such as in the case of `INFINITY`), an EQUAL TO comparison to it will always hold true?

Comment: @cupic: If `x` and `y` represent the same number, `x == y` evaluates to true. That is the rule, period. `x` and `y` may be the result of prior approximations, but that is a separate matter. Once the values of `x` and `y` are set floating-point `x` and `y` do not contain any information about what values they might “approximate” or any range of numbers they approximate other than a single point: the one number that each represents.

Answer (score 2):

> You cannot compare two floating-point numbers with simple logic operators and expect a logical result.

There are traps surrounding comparing two floating-point numbers because they might not be exactly what you expect due to rounding error due lack of precision. Sometimes, a number is very close to but not exactly what we expect. And this is what causes problems.

This problem doesn't apply to +Inf. +Inf can't accidentally be stored as some number very close to +Inf. +Inf is a specific bit pattern. It's not something like INT_MAX; it's a value that's special to the processor itself.

Same goes for -Inf.

Comment: What about NAN? Is it not just infinity with a bit to the right?

Comment: Semantics matter. NaN = Not a Number. There is no ordering between numbers (whether finite or infinite) and something that is not a number. By the same token, there is no ordering between NaNs with different bit patterns.

Comment: Re "*What about NAN?*", Isn't NaN guaranteed to be unequal to every number including itself (at least in IEEE floats)?

Comment: @ikegami That is true, and explains the second part of my question. I did not know that, however, until reading Eric  Postpischil's answer.